# Find mismatching files in two folders with bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two folders - FolderA and FolderB - each containing thousands of files that should be named exactly the same *before* the extension.  One folder contains files with .jpg extension and the other with .txt extension.

My objective is to find any files that are in one but not in the other.  So for example if FolderA contains:

```
foo.jpg
bar.jpg
baz.jpg
```

and FolderB contains:

```
foo.txt
baz.txt
qux.txt
```

The script should return:

```
FolderA/bar.jpg
FolderB/qux.txt
```

How would it be possible with bash to create such an output by inputting two separate directories ?  I was hoping to somehow modify the `diff` command which would give the `Only in ...` output but in this case since the extensions are different, `diff` would output all files

```
diff -rq FolderA FolderB
```

Comment: Yes, have you tried anything and bumped into specific problems?

Comment: I've only tried the `diff` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you ask, but reports the results in 3 columns - those unique to the first directory, those unique to the second and those common to both:

```
comm <(cd FolderA && printf "%s\n" *.jpg | sed 's/.jpg$//') <(cd FolderB && printf "%s\n" *.txt | sed 's/.txt$//')
```

**Sample Output**

```
bar
        baz
        foo
    qux
```

You could suppress printing of column 3 with:

```
comm -3 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

assume your filenames don't have special chars (like `.` or `/`), this awk "one-liner" will do the job:

```
awk -F'[./]' 'NR==FNR{a[$(NF-1)]=$0;next}
        $(NF-1) in a{delete a[$(NF-1)];next}
        {print}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' 
       <(find DIR1/ -name *.jpg) 
       <(find DIR2/ -name *.txt)
```

- you replace the `DIR1` and `DIR2` by your real dir names
- **if your filenames do contain special chars**, you need to quote the filenames or just cut the suffix. But it is the details of implementation, and it is not difficult. This answer shows you the direction to solve the problem.

Comment: Love it! A "one-liner" just with 4 linefeeds in it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your output of `diff -rq` is good, but you just want it formatted differently, you can use `sed` to change the output:

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2 | sed 's/Only in //;s/: /\//' | sort
```

That is assuming your directories do'nt have `:` (colon-space) in their name.